# IPv6 connection stops working over time

Tags: vmware-esxi, ipv6, ubuntu-16.04

I have configured IPv6 for most of my servers, which are all running `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` as Virtual Machine on `VMWare ESXi 6.5`, but after some time (sometimes a couple of hours, sometimes days) I need to reset the interface for it to work again.

**reset command**

```
sudo su && ifdown eth0 && ip addr flush dev eth0 && ifup eth0
```

What is configured incorrectly ?

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 136.xxx.154.30/24
        gateway 136.xxx.154.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
        address 136.xxx.155.179/24
        gateway 136.xxx.155.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

iface eth0 inet6 static
        address 2a01:xxx:fff7:33e::10:d1
        netmask 48
        gateway 2a01:xxx:fff7::1
        dns-nameservers 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844
```

Comment: My first guess would be that something is wrong with your firewall settings so that it blocks ICMPv6 traffic. If that's the case then once your neighbour discovery cache entries expire it won't be able to learn them again. As a start try just allowing all ICMPv6 traffic. If that works then think carefully why you would want to block each ICMPv6 type before blocking them again, if at all.